# Get the text within children nodes using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have the following html page structure:

```
<div class="result-row clearfix">
    <span>Name1</span>
    <span>city1</span>
    <span>phone1</span>
    <span>details1</span>
</div>
<div class="result-row clearfix">
    <span>Name2</span>
    <span>city2</span>
    <span>phone2</span>
    <span>details2</span>
</div>
... 
... many such similar divs
```

And I got simple input field from the user

```
<label for="name">Name</label> <br />
<input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" /> <br />

<label for="city">City</label> <br />
<input type="text" name="city" autocomplete="off" /> <br />
```

On it's blur event, I would like to make invisible all such div's that does not have the text to be searched and just show the div's that has matched (i.e. the div that has the text within the span tag).

I am not able to retrieve and match this using jquery. I have tried the following:

```
var nodes = $(".result-row");
console.log("Nodes length: "+nodes.length);  // Displays the correct number of child nodes

for(var i=0;i < nodes.length; i++) {
    var cur = nodes[i];
    console.log(cur);  // Displays '#text' in browser js console log.
    console.log(cur.childNodes[0]);  // Gives undefined. Expecting to get the 1st span tag here.
}
```

#### EDIT

I need to display the rows that has the span with matching text. Have updated the html little bit, Please refer to the updated question.

I am able to get the complete data as text of all the span's combined. Is there any way to get the array of spans inside the particular div?

Comment: i'm not sure here, but maybe you should be doing something like `nodes.get(i)` for the actual element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nodes[i] is a jquery object, which doesn't have childNodes property i guess.. so you should be using nodes[i].get(0).childNodes instead...

Comment: Thanks. This too solved my problem. I could easily now traverse the dom using `get()`. Was missing this part :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `:contains` selector:

```
var $row = $('.result-row');
$('input[type=text]').blur(function() {
    var val = this.value;
    $row.hide();
    $row.has('span:contains("'+val+'")').show()
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x3VtX/

Comment: Hey, that helps. But, I had shortened the problem for asking sake. There are 5 such input fields, and each div has five such spans. And I would like to hide the div rows if the respective span's text get matched. Hope I am clear. Please let me know if you have any doubt. Thanks